# Select first child with specific class inside a table and hide it

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I'm using the following code to hide the first child of class.

```css
.remRef {
   display: none
}

.remRef~.remRef {
   display: block
}
```

```html
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRef">link1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRef">link2</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRef">link3</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's not working inside the table. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You're using an adjacent sibling selector and your elements are not siblings. You will need Javascript

Comment: every link has that class?

Comment: Yes. I need it using only css. Is there any way?

Comment: so if all the links have the same class wouldn't it be the same if you only hide the link inside the first <tr>?

Comment: To hide the first link:       table tr:first-child > td .remRef { display: none; }

Comment: Thanks @arvie. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below example. hope this helps!

```css
table tr:first-child {
    display: none;
   }
```

```html
<table width="200" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRef">link1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRef">link2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRef">link3</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I can't use table tr:first-child  selector, because I have lot of other columns. This is just a sample code. I need to hide it using class name  remRef.